# How to make shapes move to mouse position and disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**Plunker:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/7XslB1DDwLsAV6YAurFO?p=preview

---

**What I have:**

Circles appear randomly on a set radius when the mouse moves.

---

**What I want:**

The newly appeared circles move towards the mouse while getting smaller and disappear when very small.

Think of it as some gravity effect or the mouse being a magic wand that concentrates energy.

---

**Question:**

How can I achieve what I want on the `canvas` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?
(See the code changes for info)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
 
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            function createImageOnCanvas(imageId) {
                canvas.style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("circles").style.overflowY = "hidden";
                var img = new Image(300, 300);
                img.src = document.getElementById(imageId).src;
                context.drawImage(img, (0), (0)); //onload....
            }
            
            var circles = [];
            var pos = {x:0, y:0};

            function draw(e) {
                  context.clearRect(0,0,1000,1000);
                          
              for(var i=0; i<circles.length; i++) {
                  
                  var circle = circles[i];
                  
                  var x = circle.x + circle.radius*Math.cos(circle.angle);
                  var y = circle.y + circle.radius*Math.sin(circle.angle);

                  context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)";
                  context.beginPath();
                  context.arc(x, y, 10 * circle.radius/50, 0, 2*Math.PI);
                  context.fill();
              }
                
            }
            
            // we are storing the mouse position on move
            // to be used by animation rendering when needed

            var mouseMoved = false;
            function onMouseMove(evt)  {
              storeMousePosition(evt);
              
              // enable new circle creation
              mouseMoved = true;
            }
            
            
            function storeMousePosition(evt) {
              var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
              pos = {
                x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
                y: evt.clientY - rect.top
              };              
            }
            
            // update positions and sizes of circles
            // remove ones smaller 
            // create new circles if mouse is moved
            function updateCircles() {
              var ncircles = [];
              for(var i=0; i<circles.length; i++) {
                var circle = circles[i];
                if(circle.radius > 5) {
                  circle.sradius--;
                  if(circle.sradius < 40) {
                    circle.radius--;
                    circle.x = pos.x;
                    circle.y = pos.y;
                  }
                  ncircles.push(circle);
                }
              }
              if(mouseMoved) {
                // disable creating new circlus 
                // if mouse is stopped
                mouseMoved = false;
                
              
                posx = pos.x;
                posy = pos.y;

                var radius = 50;  
                
                var angle=Math.random()*Math.PI*2;
                
                ncircles.push({
                  radius: radius,
                  sradius: radius,
                  angle: angle,
                  x: pos.x,
                  y: pos.y
                })
              }
                
              circles = ncircles;
              draw();
            }
            

            window.draw = draw;
            
            // update circles and re-render the frame
            // in every 40 milliseconds
            setInterval(updateCircles, 40);
```

```css
canvas {
                border: 1px solid #000;
                background-color: black;
                margin-left: -10px;
                margin-top: -10px;
            }
```

```html
<div id="circles"></div>
        <canvas  id="canvas" onmousemove="onMouseMove(event)"></canvas>
```

I think adding some more info about how to approach this kind of requirements would be good.

"... move towards the mouse while getting smaller and disappear ..."

As this requirement sounds there should be a little animation involved, we need to separate the "calculation" and "rendering" so we need to keep record of the objects, their colors, sizes, positions etc. to render the "next" frame. We can delete an object from our record, if we no longer see it visible.

On rendering stage, we need to get our array of objects to be rendered and draw them one-by-one to the canvas. But before we need to clear the previous frame (or more advanced, part of the changed region but for now let's clear the whole canvas) and draw everything. And this should be done in several times in a second just like in the movies.

p.s setInterval is not the ideal method but since the question was not related to animation I tried to keep things quick and simple on the example code. [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) is a better method to do this kind of operations.

Comment: Why did you change `draw(event)` to `onMouseMove(event)` ? Where is `onMouseMove(e)` in your javascript ?

Comment: I added some more comments in the code. Everything is there.

Comment: Could you please put all that in a plunker ?

Comment: Upvote. @Coder1000. The code you want is in the answer's Snippet and you can, of course, put it into a plunker -- or any other environment you require. ;=)

Comment: @markE I know :D It just makes for a cleaner answer ;) But if Bulent Vural doesn't want to put it in a plunker, I will accept it as is.